# Can't install GNOME shell extensions?

Tags: gnome, software-installation, extension

New to Ubuntu.
When I tried to get the GNOME user theme extension from the [website](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/19/user-themes/), it would not load the button to install. So I tried the command in the terminal

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell-extensions-user-theme
and got the error message:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package gnome-shell-extensions-user-theme
```

any help? Thanks!
UPDATE:
it's not the lack of an extension, I know I have it installed, and there is no pink banner. The page does not load any button for me to install (or the user reviews section.) The page does load on chromium (with the pink banner though, no extension) so I don't think its a network issue. Also, the 'duplicate'page is not my exact issue. And I tried this on firefox, which has the right extension on it by default.

Comment: Which browser did you use? Is the Gnome integration plugin enabled?

Comment: Why not using Ubuntu Software Center ?

Comment: I downloaded gnome-shell-extensions-3.13.91.tar.xz and the user-theme extension is indeed included in the archive. No instructions to install it are in the archive, but it looks like you need to run the following 8 commands from the terminal: 1. `cd ~/Downloads` 2. `wget -c https://git.gnome.org/browse/gnome-shell-extensions/snapshot/gnome-shell-extensions-3.13.91.tar.xz` 3. `tar xf gnome-shell-extensions-3.13.91.tar.xz` 4. `cd gnome-shell-extensions-3.13.91` 5. `./autogen.sh` 6. `./configure` 7. `make` 8. `sudo make install`

Comment: @karel after step 2 it said "ERROR 404: Not Found."

Comment: I visited the webpage at https://git.gnome.org/browse/gnome-shell-extensions/. There's a link to manually download gnome-shell-extensions-3.13.91.tar.xz on that webpage. The download link is working. Manually download it to your Downloads folder and continue to step 3.

Comment: @karel it says that there is no such file or directory after I downloaded it and ran the command

Comment: Here is the explanation of the steps. 1. Change directories to your Downloads directory. 2. Still in the Downloads directory, download your file. 3. Unpack the archive. It will create a new directory called *gnome-shell-extensions-3.13.91* with the installation files in it. 4. Change directories to the new directory. 5.-8. These 4 steps install gnome-shell-extensi‌​ons. All the filenames and the names of the directories are case sensitive and have to match EXACTLY.

Comment: @karel ok i got a little farther, now when I try to run "./autogen.sh" it says I need to install gnome-common from GNOME Git; which I tried to do by downloading a .tar.xz file from here (https://git.gnome.org/browse/gnome-common/) but IDK what the next step is to download it. (and thank you for putting up with all this)

Comment: The message you got was "You need to install gnome-common from GNOME Git (or from your OS vendor's package manager)". Well, gnome-common is in the Ubuntu Software Center, so it would be easier to just install that. The last line of the install script is looking for a file called gnome-autogen.sh which is included in gnome-common from the Ubuntu Software Center.

Answer (score 4):

You can install only official gnome extensions available in Ubuntu repo using `sudo apt-get install gnome-shell-extensions`.

To install other extensions you need Firefox browser. Visit https://extensions.gnome.org/ to install all the available extention.

If you see webpage like this [image]

It means that you need to install  [GNOME 3 Integration](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/collections/seleznev/gnome3/) plugin in your browser. Install it from [here](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/collections/seleznev/gnome3/).

Once plugin added to your browser, you can install all the available extensions from https://extensions.gnome.org/.

Comment: Yeah I have the extension, and that's the problem. There is no pink banner, but also no button, and the user reviews section never loads. I tried it on chromium (no extension) and the page loads fine, but with the pink banner so I don't think its a network issue.